# finding all iterations of an element in a tuple and returning its pair

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples, element

So I have a list of tuples that looks something like:

```
visits_country = (['123', 'United States'], ['456', 'United States'], ['1', 'Canada'], ['24', 'Canada'], ['12', 'Mexico'])
```

I've managed to sum all of the first entries which have a second entry 'United States' as follows

```
us_visits = [x[0] for x in visits_country if x[1] == 'United States']
total_us_visits = sum(map(int, us_visits))
```

Is there a way to automate this task so that I don't have to write a whole new line for every single country to sum all of its paired integers? Possibly a function that will return a list with each unique country and its total visits from each occurrence in the original list (visits_country)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
visits_country = (['123', 'United States'], ['456', 'United States'], 
                  ['1', 'Canada'], ['24', 'Canada'], ['12', 'Mexico'])

dictionary = {}

for count, country in visits_country:
    dictionary[country] = dictionary.get(country, 0) + int(count)

print dictionary
```

Comment: That returns a list of 'Country': [1, 2, 3] . How do I modify that such that it will return a list 'Country': [sum(1, 2, 3)]? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yup. The most obvious approaches are to use either [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), the latter requiring a presort. For example:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

visits_country.sort(itemgetter(1))
sums = [(sum(int(x) for _, x in grp), key)
        for key, grp in groupby(visits_country, itemgetter(1))]
```

or:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
for visits, country in visits_country:
    counts[country] += int(visits)
```

Comment: Why do use import if we have standard tools?

Comment: @Siddhant Are you kidding me? Simple tools? What's difficult in the task? It is a simple task in two lines of code (maybe one if we will use a generator of dictionaries)

Comment: @JRazor: Because stuff like `Counter` (or `defaultdict(int)`) allows you to simplify actual use from `counts[country] = counts.get(country, 0) + int(visits)` to `counts[country] += int(visits)` and `Counter` has a number of additional utility methods for getting the most common items. Because `groupby` is more efficient in the case where the input is already sorted. Because the whole point of having built-in libraries is to push more of the implementation into common code so we aren't writing it by hand? These aren't obscure third party packages, they're standard Python modules.

Comment: In fact, in this case, the presort isn't actually needed for the `groupby` case (assuming the example data is in fact in the order given, with all data for the same country grouped), so dropping the `sort` would still leave `groupby` equally efficient and have it preserve the original order.

Comment: Dictionary of Python provides ample opportunity to work with him. I don't think it is worth importing this stuff for such a simple task.

Comment: @JRazor: I'd agree that `groupby` is rather more special purpose, but frankly, using something like `defaultdict(int)` (or `Counter`) makes for more faster, more readable code, even for "simple tasks". When the goal is to have a default on every access, it's a lot easier to build that default into the type itself, not manually handle it on every use.